# What is the median of the $6$ terms?

Tags: means

Can anyone help me with this? The problem seems quite simple, but I can't get the same answer as the answer sheet. My answer to this question is $9$, but the answer sheet is $54$.

> In a sequence of $6$ positive integers, each term after the first is determined by multiplying the proceeding term by $2$.The mean of the $6$ term terms is $94.5$ What is the median of the $6$ terms?

Comment: It may be helpful for you to show how you got $9$ as the answer...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

The terms are $a,2a,4a,8a,16a,32a.$ The mean is

$$\frac{a+2a+4a+8a+16a+32a}{6}=\frac{63a}{6}.$$

Since you know the mean you can get $a.$

Now, isn't the median $$\frac{4a+8a}{2}=54?$$